# How to load page on button click using jquery ajax and Php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How to load page on button click and pass data to that new page using jquery ajax and place the value in input field into new loaded page?.Basically, what I am saying is,

I have a button named SOmething and I just want by clicking on this button the show.php page should load without refreshing and the value 123 I recieved in success function should be placed in input field defined in show.php.so far I've done this.

**index.php**

```
<div id='page_details'>
<div class="container  border w-25 mt-3 p-2">
 <div class="border p-3 my-3">
    <a class="text-dark call" href='#' id='number'>SOmething</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

  $.ajax({
        url: 'show.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            number: '123' 
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#page_details").load('show.php', {
                'data': data
            });  
        }
    });
```

**show.php**

Getting undefined index number errror.

```
 $number = $_POST['number'];
 $data = $_POST['data'];

<div class="col">
  <p>Amount</p>
  <input class='form-control' value='<?php echo $number ?>'/>  
 <input class='form-control' value='<?php echo $data ?>'/>  //It loads another page within page..
</div>
```

Even though I got number 123 in console but is not showing in input field...

Regards..

Comment: You have invalid JSON -> `number: 123'` You need to have quotes either at both sides of the value, or neither (since it's a number).  Also, get rid of the AJAX call - the `load()` is doing everything you need.

Comment: @Archer Thanx for replying.I misplaced 123' here but not in the actual code.I updatad the code.but I am not getting any value and it loads the whole page content within page loads.SO there would be two pages up and down.

Answer (score 2):

First: understand the "show.php" file , here you received two value so you need to pass data parameter also,
Second: User html comment under html tag

Now solution for your problem below, just use below script:

```
$("#number").on("click", function(){
 $.ajax({
   url: 'show.php',
   method: 'POST',
   data: {
      number: '123',
      data: 'pankaj' 
     },
   success: function(data) {
   console.log(data);
   $("#page_details").html(data);
  }
 });
});
```