# Prevent loading specific block by default and only load on click specific div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

We have a specific block that we would prevent from loading it's html by default on page rendering. Not easily add a display none, but prevent entire loading. This because of SEO/Indexing.

We would like to load the entire content on clicking another element `<div class="product-blog-block-item col ">`. How can we achieve this?

Code:

```
<div class="product-blog-block-item col ">
    <span>Show blog</span>
</div>

<div class="blog-content">
    <?php echo $post->getFullContent(); ?>          
</div>
```

Comment: It is not related to PHP if you don't share PHP related problems (PHP is server-side, it has nothing to do with click events and styling). Use the right tags.

Comment: Use JS and CSS to hide and show the div

Comment: @ADyson Thanks a lot! But we really would like to prevent the content from loading, not only hide it with a display none. How can we achieve that?

Comment: Don't put `<?php echo $post->getFullContent(); ?> ` into the page, then. And if you want it to load later, use JS and AJAX to fetch the content via a separate request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Edited answer with data prevent from loading:***

**1. Move PHP to a Separate File:**

*yourfile.php*

```
<?php
    echo $post->getFullContent();
?>
```

**2. AJAX Request on Click:**

*yourpage.php*

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".product-blog-block-item.col").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'yourfile.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { ... },  // If POST info needed
            success: function(response) {
                $('.blog-content').html(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

<div class="product-blog-block-item col ">
    <span>Show blog</span>
</div>

<div class="blog-content">
    <!-- Content will load here upon clicking the above div -->
</div>
```

---

***Old answer***

You can use CSS and JavaScript

**1. Hide the Content Initially**

Use CSS to hide the blog-content div initially.

```
<style>
    .blog-content {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

**2. JavaScript to Toggle Display**

Use JavaScript to toggle the display of the blog-content div when the product-blog-block-item div is clicked.

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
        const blogItem = document.querySelector('.product-blog-block-item');
        const blogContent = document.querySelector('.blog-content');

        blogItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (blogContent.style.display === 'none' || blogContent.style.display === '') {
                blogContent.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                blogContent.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This code doesn't prevent it from being loaded, but it does hide it (*I've just seen your edited post*). To manage loading, I think you'd have to use AJAX:

- https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp
- [jQuery/AJAX - Load content into a div when button clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787494/jquery-ajax-load-content-into-a-div-when-button-clicked)
- [How to load page on button click using jquery ajax and Php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57026105/how-to-load-page-on-button-click-using-jquery-ajax-and-php)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But we really would like to prevent the content from loading, not only hide it with a display none. How can we achieve that?

Comment: Just edited the answer with an AJAX example.